# SQL Update Text from another Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, wordpress

this is my first question to S.O. so plz forgive the noobiness. Im also not that crash hot with SQL so I appreciate any advice on this.

I have on table *wp_6_posts* which has column named *post_content* and in that column on various rows is a text string with format:

```
http://www.domain.com/52
http://www.domain.com/182
http://www.domain.com/122
```

In another table *wp_6_pmlca_links* there are rows with ID numbers that match the numbers at the end of the URl above.  Also in that table is the column *afflink* which contains the URL I need (it is the only content in that field).

What I need to do is replace the entire first URL in *post_content* with the URL from the corresponding *afflink* row.

Any/all advice is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

For example, currently the *post_content* column contains the text of the post for that row.  It can be several thousand characters long, but within it will be either 1, or a number of URLS with the synatx above, usually in a href tag:

```
Text here to <a href="http://www.domain.com/23">Text for link</a>
```

The link that corresponds to the number in the URL is stored in a separate table as mentioned above.  The row structure for that is:

```
ID | slug | URL |
----------------
23 |  23  | http://www.externaldomain.com/link |
```

What I need to do is identify the first URL, query to find the corresponding URL and the replace the first URL with the second.

I have no idea what SQL syntax to use to construct the query Im sorry :(

Comment: Please show example. (Sample input and expected output). Also share the table structures of the related tables.

Comment: Domain name will be remain same or what else?

Comment: Yes the domain will remain the same @yatinparab

Comment: see posted solution hope it will work

Comment: thanks guys, just waiting on a DEV environment setup from the IT guys so I can test this safely

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your data in `wp_6_pmlca_links`, but try this(for Mysql):

```
UPDATE wp_6_posts t1
JOIN wp_6_pmlca_links t2
ON t2.ID = substring_index(t1.post_content, '/', -1)
// For sql server, 'substring_index(t1.post_content, '/', -1)' should be 'right(t1.post_content, len(t1.post_content) - charindex(replace(t1.post_content, '//', '$$'), '/'))'
SET t1.post_content = t2.afflink
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This but this query i wrote in sql.

```
update a
set a.post_content =b.URL 
from wp_6_posts a 
inner join wp_6_pmlca_links  b on convert(int,replace(a.post_content,'http://www.domain.com/',''))=b.id
```

This will works for mysql also.